# Unload file in Pyswip

Tags: python, prolog, ffi

I am using Pyswip. I have some Python code like. In the first iteration, I load file1. In the second iteration, I load file2.

```
for i in [1, 2]
  prolog = Prolog()
  prolog.consult(f'file{i}')
```

However, even if I use a new Prolog() object in the second iteration, the facts in file1 still exist. I hope in the second iteration, aftet prolog.consult(file2), only the facts in file2 exist.

How do I do this? Currently, I fork a new child process each iteration. It is very awkward